# symfony 2.2 Forms: Numeric Value in Option FieldType

Tags: php, forms, symfony, html-select

I would like to implement a select box in which the user can choose a support team he wants to contact.
Every team has his own number and these numbers are not consecutive numbers.

So I add this array to the choice box:

```
array('1' => 'Team A', '123' => 'Team B')
```

But the select box says now:

```
<select [...]>
<option value="0">Team A</option>
<option value="1">Team B</option>
</select>
```

{{ dump(options) }} in {% block choice_widget_options %} shows me this:

```
array(2) {   
    [0] =>   class Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\View\ChoiceView#1538 (3) {     public $data =>     int(0)     public $value =>     string(1) "0"     public $label =>     string(17) "Team A"   }
    [1] =>   class Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\View\ChoiceView#1539 (3) {     public $data =>     int(1)     public $value =>     string(1) "1"     public $label =>     string(19) "Team B"   

}
```

Does anybody know how I can fix this?

Comment: PS: The problem is that the values are now 0 and 1 instead of 1 and 123 :)

Comment: could you insert  formType class of this

Comment: @mohsenkw It's an custom form type extending Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType

Answer (score 1):

well you added the keys as strings

```
array('1' => 'Team A', '123' => 'Team B')
```

change to

```
array(1 => 'Team A', 123 => 'Team B')
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem. It would be confusing if it would because you can also set strings als values ('f' => 'female') : http://symfony.com/doc/2.2/reference/forms/types/choice.html

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys I found the problem :)

I use "array_shift($choices);" later to delete the first team (default value) from the array. This changes the keys to 0,1,2,3,4 and so on.